# Is there an image database for damaged highways and other damaged infrastructure?

Tags: image, image-processing, feature-detection, infrastructure

I am currently working on a research topic that involves infrastructure damage detection. For this, I need a collection of pictures of roads/highways with damages.

If possible, I could also use a collection of pictures for other infrastructure with damage; by other infrastructure, I mean bridges, dams, etc.

Does anyone know of any such image database?

Comment: Contact these folks: http://www.umtri.umich.edu

Comment: if this is a long-term interest I may be able to send you more references. At least one company, Mandli (http://mandli.com), was devoting the right resources to this problem the last I knew, though that was a little over 10 years ago now.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a long team interest, but this is for a project I am working on for my thesis.